# Addition of plugins to React native app without using expo and without modifiying AndroidManifest.xml and info.plist files

Tags: plugins, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to add plugins like camera, scanner in an react-native-app but this involves addition of some additional code into AndroidManifest.xml and info.plist file for enabling plugin permissions
Whereas I would like to add the plugins at one place and it should update in appropriate Android and iOS files, similar to that of config.xml file configuration in cordova apps.

Are there any libraries available to implement in this way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. Adding libraries that deal with permissions has always been a bit of a struggle in react native, where you have to touch the android and iOS files and often times specify why your app requires those permissions in the first place. It gets a bit more complicated as different android versions have different ways to deal with permissions.

The good news is that most of the libraries you'll want to add provide a detailed documentation on how to set them up properly which does not take too long after you get the gist of it.